# Fixing SSH access lost with rsa key

Tags: permissions, sshd

### Background

I have a server set up with SSH access via ras keys. Password access is not permitted.

It was working fine. My user (I'll called that USER1) and root could log in with their respective keys.

### CHANGES THAT POTENTIALLY CAUSED ISSUE

Yesterday I made a few changes to the server, following the instructions [in this article](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-an-sftp-user-with-limited-access-on-ubuntu/), in order to grant a new user (USER2) limited access to one folder (the web root). I also followed instructions in [this article](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-an-sftp-user-with-limited-access-on-ubuntu/).

To summarise those changes, I created a new user (USER2), and did a `bindfs` of the web root (`/home/user1/sites/domain/public/`) to `/home/user2/domain/public/`). There were a few other things done, as per those articles, but as far as I can tell none of them impact on the permissions and SSH access of USER1. So I won't try reiterating them all here.

As per one of those articles, I also added the following to the `sshd_config` file:

```
subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User USER2
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

As far as I can tell, that's the only thing that has changed since I was last able to log in with USER1.

### ISSUE

After making the above-mentioned changes, I was not able to log in the next day (today). I get the error, `Permission denied (publickey).`.

I've followed all the standard recommendations to set the right permissions and ownership for the `~/home/USER1/.ssh` folder, and `~/home/USER1/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Although, none of them were changed by my actions yesterday, so I was basically just reapplying the existing permissions.

The content of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file is:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
UsePAM yes
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match User USER2
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

`AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` was perviously commented out. I uncommented it whilst trying to fix this issue.

I am at a loss as to what is preventing my USER1 from having key based SSH access. If there is any further information that would be helpful, please let me know.

## UPDATE: Managed to fix it, but not sure why it occured

Having double checked that all permissions were correct, and there was nothing odd in the `sshd-config` file, I set ssh to permit password login, and then recopied my id_rsa.pub file (using `ssh-copy-id`) to the server.

This has restored my access for USER1 with a key.

I don't totally understand why this issue occured, and I plan on using the instructions in those articles on additional servers (as it proved to be a very useful way to grant a developer (for example) strict SFTP access (only) to the web site, and have permission to make file changes. So if anyone has the time to point out what the error was in the instructions, please do.

To save you from reading those articles, here is a break down of the steps I took:

```
mkdir -p /home/user2/websites/application1
chown -Rf user2:user2 /home/user2/websites
chmod -Rf 770 /home/user2/websites
```

Add following to `/etc/fstab`

```
bindfs#/home/user1/websites/domain/public /home/user2/websites/application1 fuse force-user=user2,force-group=user2,create-for-user=user1,create-for-group=user1,create-with-perms=0770,chgrp-ignore,chown-ignore,chmod-ignore 0 0

chown user1:user1 /home/user1/websites/domain/public
chmod 770 /home/user1/websites/domain/public
```

Created the new user:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/user2/website/application1 user2
sudo passwd user2
```

Added to sshd-config

```
subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User user2
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then, `sudo service ssh restart`

## QUESTION

So my modified question is, what in the above steps would have caused `user1` from having ssh access with its key?

Comment: sshd itself provides very useful information if you use LogLevel DEBUG3.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering how to get more useful info out of SSHD logging. Was telling me almost nothing.